# Array split bz count of number

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, project

I've got this problem from my prof.

Take an integer N and an Array A (non-empty) having X integer numbers. You need to split the Array A into two parts from where the first Array Ax (Left Array) contains the numbers equals to Integer N and Array Ay (Right Array) Contains the same number of non N integers.

Means the Index (I) of A should be 0 < = I < X

Elements in Ax must be equals to integer X and Elements in Ay must not be equals to integer X

the number of elements equal to X in A[0..I-1] is the same as the number of elements different from X in A[I..N-1].(For K = 0, A[0..I-1] does not contain any elements. For I  = N, A[I ..N-1] does not contain any elements.)

**for example**
If X = 3 and array var **A = [3, 3, 4, 9, 2, 5, 3]**

Asymmetry Index I = 4

As for I = 3 the parts of Array A will be Ax = [3, 3, 4, 9] and Ay = [2, 5, 3]. In which the two element of Array Ax are equals to N and two elements from Array Ay are not equals to X

**assume, that**
X is an integer and can be from 1 to 100000

N is an integer and can be 0 to 100000

Elements of Array A are integers and can be from 0 to 100000

1. WorstCase time complexity must be O(N)
2. WorstCase space complexity must be O(1), storage of input is not considered.

Elements of input array can be modified

```
    public static int Test1Method(int X, int[] A)
    {
                    int c, j;
        int countLeft, countRight;
        int returnIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            countLeft = 0;
            countRight = 0;
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                if (A[j] == X)
                    countLeft = countLeft + 1;
            }
            for (c = A.Length - 1; c > i; c--)
            {
                if (A[c] != X)
                    countRight = countRight + 1;
            }
            if (countRight == countLeft)
                returnIndex = i + 1;
        }

        int countX = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < returnIndex; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] == X)
                countX++;
        }

        if (countX == 0)
            return A.Length;

        return returnIndex;
    }
```

I've been told, that my solution is only functional for 10%. But I don't know why, I've tried every possible example and it works for me.

Comment: When splitting the array do the elements have to be sequential to the starting array?  Can Ax be [3,3,4,2,5,3] and Ay be []?

Comment: The question doesn't restrict you to have the array elements shuffled. The line "elements in Ax must be equal to integer X", does that mean the number of elements or the element values in Ax.

Comment: @jdweng I am not sure about this, but I can it be like that. Because of this part:
_the number of elements equal to X in A[0..I-1] is the same as the number of elements different from X in A[I..N-1].(For K = 0, A[0..I-1] does not contain any elements. For I = N, A[I ..N-1] does not contain any elements.)_ **but I am not sure about that**

Comment: @jeffrycopps I've modified the question, I forgot to add Elements of input array can be modified

and for this array **[3, 3, 4, 9, 2, 5, 3]** index should be **4** not 3

Comment: Could you please explain "elements in Ax must be equal to X. " ?

Comment: @jeffrycopps we have to split array into 2 parts, such that the number of elements equal to X in first part is equal to number of elements not equal to X

Answer (score 1):

I think your current solution works but it runs in a O(N^2) complexity.

Here's a solution which would run in a O(N) complexity, by first counting the number of X's in the array, and then looking for the point to balance the two counts, calculating countX in the beginning helps us avoiding the two internal for loops in your code.

```
public static int FindIndexSplit(int X, int[] A)
{
    var countX = A.Count(a => a == X);
    var countXLeft = 0;
    var countNonXRight = A.Length - countX;
    for (var i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
        if (countXLeft == countNonXRight) return i;
        if (A[i] == X)
        {
            countXLeft += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            countNonXRight -= 1;
        }
    }
    return A.Length;
}
```